# Finding videos which have been annotated only once

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with the following columns:

```
id(int) 
video_name (varchar)
status (completed,pending)
last_modified (date)
date_updated (date)
reviewed_by_admin (0,1)
admin_assigned_id (7,8,9,10)
user_assigned_id (2,3,4,5,9,10,11,12,15,16,17,18,19,21,23)
```

User_asssigned_id: The id of the user who has been assigned the video.

A single video has been allotted to multiple annotators and for each of the annotator there is a new record, I am trying to find the number of records whose status is completed once and pending once i.e,  the record has been annotated by one person but still hasn't been annotated by the other person. Also, Trying to find the number of records that have been completed by both annotators.

Right now I am stuck here:

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT video_name)
FROM 'mainapp_video_assignment'
WHERE status='COMPLETED'
AND video_name NOT IN
(
    SELECT video_name
    FROM 'mainapp_video_assignment'
    WHERE status= 'PENDING'
)
```

I have uploaded a screenshot of the table here: https://ibb.co/MM7PCRC

Comment: you have a severe issue in your database layout. You should mantain a one to many relationship between video and assignees, not store all of them in a field in your table. create a table with the id of the video and as many rows as assignees for that video

Comment: the comment is valid both for admin and for users

Comment: Provide complete CREATE TABLE script, INSERT INTO script with sample data, and desired output for shown data. Include all possible combinations into the table data. Also specify precise MySQL version.

Comment: Please share more details. What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Please **don't** add screenshots of stuff that can be shared as text. Provide all details such that others can easily reproduce your problem

Comment: I have attached a link to the problem with the screenshot of the table.

Comment: Just as I wrote: don't add screenshots for stuff that can be shared as text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's first count the number of rows with PENDING / COMPLETED status values for each video:

```sql
select
  video_name,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 'COMPLETED' THEN 1 END) completed_count,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 'PENDING' THEN 1 END) pending_count,
from 'mainapp_video_assignment'
group by video_name
```

We can then easily check for all videos with exactly one pending and exactly one completed row:

```sql
select video_name
from
  (select
    video_name,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 'COMPLETED' THEN 1 END) completed_count,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 'PENDING' THEN 1 END) pending_count,
  from 'mainapp_video_assignment'
  group by video_name)
where
  completed_count = 1 and
  pending_count = 1
/* Alternatively:
 * completed_count = 2 and
 * pending_count = 0
*/
```

Thanks to @Akina for the suggestion.

Comment: Conditional aggregation instead of 2 subqueries may be more useful.

Comment: what does the second query intend to do?

Comment: @ROHITDUBEY, I've updated the solution since you'd asked. What it does now is check for each video how many times it appears as completed vs pending based on the earlier aggregation, hope this helps

Comment: For the particular case of MySQL, CASE, WHEN, THEN, 1, and END are redundant (...when replacing COUNT with SUM) - and anything in inverted commas is a string

Comment: Some syntaxes also support `COUNTIF` out-of-the-box but I didn't want to make any software-specific assumptions